# How to configuration CodeMirror 3 with HTML + CSS + JavaScript + PHP + SQL?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I use CodeMirror 3.16 for edit code, but I have to set the better "mode" for my files but somes have multi language inside like a PHP with HTML + CSS + JavaScript + PHP + SQL but I don't know how to define for all :(
I've found a doc but for CodeMirror 1.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE I FOUND THAT:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027884/how-to-combine-multiple-modes-in-codemirror-while-showing-preview
But it's not for my use

Comment: Actually [php mode](http://codemirror.net/mode/php/) supports `html` and embedded `js`, `css`... and there's no way for editor to guess, that some string actually contain SQL code, hence it is impossible to add SQL hilight for that.

Comment: @kirilloid I wouldn't say there is *no* way for an editor to guess. I know that at least one popular syntax highlighting library can guess what language some code is in, by counting keywords in the code and comparing them to the keywords in a language. It might detect SQL by detecting a relatively high number of `select`, `where`, `from`, etc. keywords.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane It just depends if you prefer stable and predicable working enviroment that doesn't highlight as much stuff as chaotic colorful code guesser.